# Read xml embedded in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, xml, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack, xmldocument

I want to read this source as xml

> http://blabla/bla.aspxPageMethod=ElencoPresentiNew&idArea=0&dtRif=&mostra=T&format=xml

That returns a result like the following (straight in the browser, not as file)

[image: Screenshot result]

I tried to use XmlDocument or Agilitypack tool, also httpwebrequest, but I get different problems. With xmldocument I get an error saying that some xml elements are missing, with the other methods I get the html source of the page but not the data.
How can I achieve what I want? Thanks

**EDIT:**
first xml lines from source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Result>
    <has_custom_url>false</has_custom_url>
    <oggi>24.10.2019</oggi>
    <utente>
        <controlli196eseguiti>true</controlli196eseguiti>
        <idprofiloutente>17</idprofiloutente>
        <dizionario>
            <u>U</u>
            <e>E</e>
        </dizionario>
        <nominativo>super</nominativo>
        <cambiopwd>1567402823277</cambiopwd>
        <descrinsediamento>Insediamento principale</descrinsediamento>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load("http://192.168.2.49/checkandin/area.aspx?PageMethod=ElencoPresentiNew&idArea=0&dtRif=&mostra=T&format=xml")
        Dim ns As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("PresentiPerAreaCalc", ns)
        Dim listaIniziale As New List(Of String)

        For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
            Dim record As String = node.SelectSingleNode("descrazienda").Value
            listaIniziale.Add(record)
        Next
```

Comment: That's just XML, not XML in an HTML page. The *browser* says that it can't display the XML file nicely because there's no stylesheet attached to it. What *exactly* happened when you tried XmlDocument? AgilityPack won't help because this isn't HTML. Did you get an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I get "Expected markup DTD not found. Row 3, position 5."

Comment: So what's at Row 3, position 5? Post the *actual* XML file and your actual code. I suspect the file is actually a fragment and is missing the `<?xml>` element?

Comment: This is the souce (first 3 lines), note that I can't edit it: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Result>
    <has_custom_url>false</has_custom_url>

Comment: Maybe there's a way to read it as it is just a text? Avoiding all the xml format issues...

Comment: It *is* text and there are no formatting issues. XML is just text. The image you posted is how the *browser* tries to display that text. Either save the document in the browser, or in your code and post the first few lines, in the question itself

Comment: ok I added the first lines to the question.

Comment: This works fine with `XmlDocument.LoadXml`. How did you try to parse it?

Comment: I added the vb code

Comment: `Load` shouldn't throw either. The *rest* may throw because there's no namespace defined in the document. `doc.SelectNodes("//descrinsediamento")` will work without a namespace

Comment: The error is right at doc.Load, it never get to doc.selectNodes

Comment: Not with the document posted here.

Comment: Ok, I tried downloading it and it gives me the same error, but It succeed if I remove the first line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?> question is, how to bypass the first line reading the document directly from url?